# The implements keyword in Java

Tags: java

I have trouble understanding `implements` keyword in Java. I believe the below table is correct but I need someone to check.

[image]

Comment: `implement` is a keyword in Java so this table is ambiguous.

Comment: Java distiguishes between "implementing" and "extending"... Basically, "implements" is used for interfaces and "extends" for classes.

Comment: The table is wrong depending on what you mean by `implement`. A class cannot `implement` another class. A class can only `extend` from another class. It's not hard to understand. It's ambiguous.

Comment: I have edited the image. Is the table correct now? I am referring to simply the `implement` keyword.

Comment: Table lools ok, but if you refer to `implements` keyword, then it's wrong. Only interfaces can be implemented.

Comment: @MichalKordas I have edited the table now, so that the only column with true's is the interface column. Is this correct, provided i'm referring to the implements keyword

Comment: @user2850514 Not yet. Interface cannot implement other interface. It can only **extend** it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concrete class and abstract class can **extend** another concrete class or abstract class and can **implement** interface.

Interface can only **extend** another interface, it cannot **extend** any class.

So if you strictly refer to `implements` keyword, then only concrete classes and abstract classes can implement interfaces. The rest of cells should be `False`.

Comment: An interface **extends** another interface, right?